# uploading a file programmatically

Tags: php, web-services, file-upload

I have a web form that can be used to upload files to our server. I'm trying to also set up programmatic uploading where the user(developer) can upload the files without needing to use the web form, sort of like an API if you want to think of it this way.

I'm not sure what this function is supposed to look like on either end: user end and my end. I'm using PHP. Can this sort of programmatic uploading be done with PHP for relatively large files (10-100MB)?

Comment: do you require progress feedback ?

Comment: @John Boker, Ideally yes, but I don't know if this will be a big deal if I don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an API that will accept POST variables. The POST variable can contain the file. The end user (or developer) can use cURL to post data to your URL.

There is no maximum size for POST. It depends on your server settings and PHP settings.