# Is it possible to get a return value with post protocol?

Tags: java, php, asp.net, web-services

Let's say I need to upload files to a server programmatically using [uploading a file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127982/uploading-a-file-programmatically) can a server whatever php java or asp.net return me a value when using `POST` request method instead of `GET` ?

If not how can I ask the server which files have been uploaded correctly or that uploads have finished ?

I mean if the server is ANOTHER server than mine I can't see how to get the response so can you give some sample code or refer to some urls.

Comment: By ANOTHER server do you mean - a service hosted by someone else on which you do not have a control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can, same way as `GET` requests e.g. server can answer with JSON format string response which will include uploaded files or it can return full html page, whatever you need.

E.g. if you want to send some data to server using `POST` method and you want to alert it you can do something like this (jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/testing.php",
  data: { name: "John Doe" } // sample data sent to server
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Response data: " + msg );
});
```

Generally it shouldn't matter if it was `GET` or `POST`, response is returned from server, the only thing you need to do is catch it and perform actions based on response content.

Comment: I don't understand: if the server is ANOTHER server than mine I can't see how to get the response. Do you have some code ?

Comment: You have posted general question, without code sample and you want code sample, this is not ok, because we don't really know what is not working. But check my edited answer

Comment: Sorry I'm not really coder, I just need to know what's possible and I can guess by reading code

Comment: Will your code with ajax work with cross domain server ? I think has cross domain problem.

Comment: Check those: [jquery-ajax-cross-domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) & [how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript), also remember that sometimes response is redirection, so you may not receive expected response string, but insead you can receive redirection response to other page

Comment: if it is redirection it means I cannot process it further on programmatically ?

Comment: No, it means that you should be redirected to other page to get answer, in this case browser would redirect out to other page, read up more about how http works, you can start with this: [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)